Issue with Drag Selection (Mouseup Event) Not Triggering Click Event in Specific Direction
I created a drag-to-select feature where, by clicking and dragging the mouse, a div element is generated to represent the selection area. The implementation works well overall, but I encountered an issue: when dragging in most directions, a click event is consistently triggered, except when I drag to the left and upwards.
I’m curious if anyone can explain why this behavior occurs. I did manage to fix it by ensuring that the selection area triggers the click event even when expanding into negative directions (left and up), but I don't fully understand why the click event wasn’t always triggered in the first place or if there’s a way to prevent it from triggering in these cases.
Here’s the not-fixed code:


$(document).ready(function () {
  let isDragging = false;
  let startX, startY;
  let selectionBox = $('<div class="selection-box"></div>');
  let selectedCount = 0;
  let select_visible = 0;

  initializeSelectionBox();

  $(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (isDragging) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // Prevent the click event if dragging occurred
      isDragging = false; // Reset dragging state
      console.log("Click prevented due to dragging.");
    } else {
      console.log("You have clicked");
    }
  });
  function initializeSelectionBox() {
    $(document).on("mousedown", "#all_files_dir", function (e) {
      startDragging(e);

      $(document)
        .on("mousemove.drag", updateSelectionBox)
        .on("mouseup.drag", stopDragging);
    });

    $(document).on("dragstart", "#all_files_dir", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }

  function startDragging(e) {
    isDragging = true;
    startX = e.clientX - $("#all_files_dir").offset().left;
    startY = e.clientY - $("#all_files_dir").offset().top;

    selectionBox.css({
      top: startY + "px",
      left: startX + "px",
      width: 0 + "px",
      height: 0 + "px",
    });

    $("#all_files_dir").append(selectionBox);
  }

  function updateSelectionBox(e) {
    if (isDragging) {
      if (!$("#all_files_dir").hasClass("drag"))
        $("#all_files_dir").addClass("drag");

      const mouseX = e.clientX - $("#all_files_dir").offset().left;
      const mouseY = e.clientY - $("#all_files_dir").offset().top;

      const width = Math.abs(mouseX - startX);
      const height = Math.abs(mouseY - startY);

      const newX = mouseX < startX ? mouseX : startX;
      const newY = mouseY < startY ? mouseY : startY;

      selectionBox.css({
        width: width + "px",
        height: height + "px",
        top: newY + "px",
        left: newX + "px",
      });
    }
  }

  function stopDragging(e) {
    if (isDragging) {
      isDragging = false;

      selectionBox.remove(); // Remove the selection box
    }

    // Remove the event listeners after dragging is done
    $(document).off("mousemove.drag");
    $(document).off("mouseup.drag");
  }
});
.selection-box {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 100, 200, 0.5);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>

<div id="all_files_dir" style="width:100%;height:100%"></div>



Here's the fixed code:


$(document).ready(function () {
  let isDragging = false;
  let startX, startY;
  let selectionBox = $('<div class="selection-box"></div>');
  let selectedCount = 0;
  let select_visible = 0;

  initializeSelectionBox();

  $(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (isDragging) {
      e.stopImmediatePropagation(); // Prevent the click event if dragging occurred
      isDragging = false; // Reset dragging state
      console.log("Click prevented due to dragging.");
    } else {
      console.log("You have clicked");
    }
  });
  function initializeSelectionBox() {
    $(document).on("mousedown", "#all_files_dir", function (e) {
      startDragging(e);

      $(document)
        .on("mousemove.drag", updateSelectionBox)
        .on("mouseup.drag", stopDragging);
    });

    $(document).on("dragstart", "#all_files_dir", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  }

  function startDragging(e) {
    isDragging = true;
    startX = e.clientX - $("#all_files_dir").offset().left;
    startY = e.clientY - $("#all_files_dir").offset().top;

    selectionBox.css({
      top: startY + "px",
      left: startX + "px",
      width: 0 + "px",
      height: 0 + "px",
    });

    $("#all_files_dir").append(selectionBox);
  }

  function updateSelectionBox(e) {
    if (isDragging) {
      if (!$("#all_files_dir").hasClass("drag"))
        $("#all_files_dir").addClass("drag");

      const mouseX = e.clientX - $("#all_files_dir").offset().left;
      const mouseY = e.clientY - $("#all_files_dir").offset().top;

      const width = Math.abs(mouseX - startX);
      const height = Math.abs(mouseY - startY);

      const newX = mouseX < startX ? mouseX : startX;
      const newY = mouseY < startY ? mouseY : startY;

      selectionBox.css({
        width: width + "px",
        height: height + "px",
        top: newY + "px",
        left: newX + "px",
      });
    }
  }

  function stopDragging(e) {
    if (isDragging) {
      isDragging = false;

      if (e.clientX - startX < 0 && e.clientY - startY < 0) {
        // Trigger a click manually
        $(e.target).trigger("click");
      }
      selectionBox.remove(); // Remove the selection box
    }

    // Remove the event listeners after dragging is done
    $(document).off("mousemove.drag");
    $(document).off("mouseup.drag");
  }
});
.selection-box {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: rgba(0, 100, 200, 0.5);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.11.3/font/bootstrap-icons.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.3.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" ></script>

<body>
    <div id="all_files_dir" style="width:100%;height:100%">

    </div>
</body>



